# as.H2O fails when there is a dollar sign: "Cannot determine file type"

Tags: r, h2o

Using the `h2o` package, I am meeting an unexpected error. While using `as.h2o` on a dataset, it returned the error `Cannot determine file type`. After a binary search, I found the problematic character: A dollar sign.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

tmp <- data.frame(text = "$", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- as.h2o(tmp)
```

And the error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ParseSetup)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine file type. for /tmp/RtmpseoDZt/file36123d495362.csv_sid_ae2a_2"
 [2] "    water.api.ParseSetupHandler.guessSetup(ParseSetupHandler.java:46)"                                                        
 [3] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                              
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                                            
 [5] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                                    
 [6] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"                                                                         
 [7] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:60)"                                                                                
 [8] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:462)"                                                                    
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:295)"                                                                
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:221)"                                                                   
[11] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                                             
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                             
[13] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                                   
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)"                                               
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                                       
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)"                                                
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                                        
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                            
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                    
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                          
[21] "    water.webserver.jetty8.Jetty8ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty8ServerAdapter.java:119)"                             
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                    
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                          
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                                  
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                           
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                            
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:984)"                                 
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1045)"                 
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)"                                                         
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:236)"                                                    
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                                   
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                             
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                         
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                          
[35] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"                                                                                    

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Cannot determine file type. for /tmp/RtmpseoDZt/file36123d495362.csv_sid_ae2a_2
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? I would like to fit a Word2Vec model, so characters are actually important.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I keep investigating about this and found some extra information. Apparently, when the dataset reaches a *big enough* size, the problem doesn't appear anymore.

I found the sweet spot at about 7000 rows. For example, with my dataset:

`tmp <- as.h2o(data[392949:399994])` doesn't return an error.

But `tmp <- as.h2o(data[392950:399994])` does return an error.

Note that the `$` character appear at index 399994. In other examples, I also found the sweet spot to be around 7000 rows (not exactly the same number all the time, just close to 7000). I couldn't build a reproducible for this by adding only `"a"` or random letters in the data.frame.

Comment: Hello Charles, I've managed to reproduce your problem and created a JIRA in H2O's system for you to track: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7149

Unfortunately, this is a fault of H2O's distributed CSV parser. The data are passed to H2O in CSV format and the CSV parser is unable to recognize the dollar sign ($) enclosed in quotes - it thinks it's currency and due to a fault in the finite state machine, it ends up running in an endless loop, until stopped by ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception (pointer overflow the chunk array).